# How to find the determinant of matrix $A$ given three equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, determinant

[image]

> Let $A\in M_{3\times 3}$ and $\vec x, \vec y, \vec z\in\mathbb R^3$. Suppose that we have
> $$A\vec x=\begin{vmatrix}1\\0\\1\end{vmatrix}, 
> A\vec y=\begin{vmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{vmatrix},
> A\vec z=\begin{vmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{vmatrix}.$$
> Then find the value of the determinant of the matrix $A$.

Started by treating each equation as a row column in a $3 \times 3$ matrix and finding the determinant of that matrix. Not sure if on the right track.

Comment: There must be more information. For instance, denote $A_{1}=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right),A_{2}=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right)$, and $x=e_{1},y=e_{2},z=e_{1}+e_{2}$, where $e_i$ is the vector of standard basis. Your assumptions hold for the two matrices but each has distinct determinant.

Comment: There is no more information.

Comment: Please take the time to enter key parts of your question—here, essentially your entire question—as text instead of pasting a picture of it. Your question should be comprehensible with images disabled. Moreover, images are neither searchable nor accessible to screen readers, nor do they show up in summaries. See the [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to format mathematical expressions.

Comment: @amd I respect your comment, and in almost all other circumstances, I think using MathJax is better than posting a picture. But in this case, I think that seeing a picture of the problem was actually more helpful than having it typed with MathJax. The OP (i.e. original poster) was asked to find $\det A$ in a situation when it is not possible to find out anything about $\det A$. If the OP had typed the question with MathJax, then I would have wondered "Was something typed in wrong? Was something left out?" Since the OP posted a picture, I think it made it easier for me to answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

In the comments, Al-Hasan Ibn Al-Hasan posted an idea that can be used to settle this question.

We were given that $A$ is $3\times3$, and that for some $\vec{x},\vec{y},\vec{z}\in\Bbb{R}^3$,

$$A\vec{x}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix},\quad A\vec{y}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix},\quad\text{and}\quad A\vec{z}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}.$$

Using this information alone, there is absolutely nothing that we can conclude about the determinant of $A$. Let's look at an example to see why.

Let $\vec{x}=e_1$, let $\vec{y}=e_2$, and let $\vec{z}=e_1+e_2$. Let $\lambda$ be your favorite scalar. If we let

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\1&0&\lambda\end{bmatrix},$$

then we can check that $A$ satisfies the given conditions, and that $\det A=\lambda$.

It follows that if the only thing we know about $A$ is that it satisfies the given conditions, then $\det A$ can be any scalar. So the given conditions don't place any restrictions on the value of $\det A$.